# Is anyone aware of specific problems with Vanmoof cranks/bottom brackets?

Tags: bottom-bracket, creak

I have a 2013 Vanmoof 5.1. I had it serviced recently by Vanmoof in Amsterdam and when I got it back, it was riding wonderfully—everything felt smooth and "free", like every little bit of power I was putting into the pedals was getting to the road.

Two weeks later and it's kind of back to where it was before the service. There is a little creaking/ticking sound coming from the cranks every turn and it feels a little like I'm riding through treacle.

Is anyone aware of a specific problem with Vanmoof bottom brackets, or could you suggest what it might be?

Comment: Note that I'm exaggerating a little for effect—it's not *that* bad as riding through treacle, and I rode the bike happily in this state for over a year before the service. It was just very noticeably better for a week or two afterward.

Comment: Have you discussed it with the people who serviced the bike?

Comment: I wanted to ask around first to see if it was a "known problem" with this model bike.

Comment: Update: I took it to another authorised Vanmoof dealer in another city who replaced the chain and the bottom bracket, but apparently the real problem is the rear wheel bearings. And replacing those basically requires a new back wheel :-(.

Answer (score 5):

I've got the same problem on (what I believe is) a 2013 3.1. I was going to try replacing/upgrading the bottom bracket myself soon, hoping to smooth out the ride.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find the size online so I'll need to take it out and inspect before I can order a replacement, hopefully this goes smoothly.

Either way, I'll update with my results when I have them.

Update: Replaced with Suntour 68x118mm Square tapered BB from local (Arlington, MA) bike shop and removed chainguard (personal preference).  Awful sound is gone... For now.

Your mileage may vary. Good luck!

Comment: BB is out. Came out fairly easily with Park Tools BBT-22. BB model is VP-BC73E.

Comment: Forgot measurements... 68+3 x 118mm. Presumably the +3 is the chain guard.